# PHP Find value in object

Tags: php, object, find, lookup

I have a result of an SQL query that looks like this

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_number] => 1
        [value] => Joe
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_number] => 2
        [value] => Bloggs
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_number] => 3
        [value] => 12566
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_number] => 4
        [value] => 2000-07-24
    )
)
```

It wont always return all the fields as some are not required therefore not saved to the database.

I know that first name is stored with field number 1. How can I look this up in the object.

EG

```
 $first_name = $result => field_number == 1
```

I know thats not right, but Im sure there must be a simple way to get this info?

Thanks

Comment: `$result[0]->value` will return `Joe`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the values in the array are not in order (eg array[0] does not always contain field_number 1) then you will need to iterate the array:

```
foreach($array as $item){
    if($item->field_number==1){
      $first_name = $item->value;
      break;
    }
}
```

However, if this is the result of an SQL query, probably you need to rewrite the query to give you data in a more useable form